# Loading array data into a tableview

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a firebase database setup that I have returning a few keys that I want. I want those keys to be the title of a tableview row. When I run the following code, it returns exactly what I want in an Array(in this example, [Athens, Delaware]). I load this array from the view did load method.

How can I get each item in the array to be a cell row in my tableView?

When I attempt to execute the following code, i get this error in return:

Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x10c7ed2c0) to 'Swift.String' (0x10c7d2888).

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

    var markets: [loadMyData] = []

    var myKey = [Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        ref.child("Markets").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            var myNewKey: [Any] = []

            let allMarkets = (snapshot.value as! NSMutableDictionary).allKeys
            myNewKey.append(allMarkets)
            self.myKey = myNewKey
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


    }
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return myKey.count

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let allMarkets = myKey[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = allMarkets as! String
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Firestore over RTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because the code `(snapshot.value as! NSMutableDictionary).allKeys` returns an array and you are adding this array as an array item to myKey! And of course, You can not cast an array to a String.

Try this code and see what happens:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

    var markets: [loadMyData] = []

    var myKey = [Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        ref.child("Markets").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            var myNewKey: [Any] = []

            let allMarkets = (snapshot.value as! NSMutableDictionary).allKeys
            self.myKey = allMarkets
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


    }
```